# In search of the Bandillo!

Tags: character-identification

I have been searching for more than a few years for an answer, and I haven't found anyone that has been able to assist. I have been reading fantasy books for 30 years, and I ran across a character or group of characters called the "Bandillo" not sure of the spelling.... but for me it’s been synonymous with thieves. I keep going back to Stephen Kings Dark Tower Series (Oy: Billy-bumbler), or The Lord of the Rings series (Tom Bombadil), but in my research and re-reading, I couldn't find anything definitive. In 30 years I have finished more than a thousand books, and have talked to enthusiast over the past five years about it, so I would have to say it’s more than 5 years old, and was at best a second or third line character in a series. Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

More information.

I have only done one series that was foreign (German). It being a translation of Bandit has been reviewed on several cases.
The main character interacts with the Bandillo, but they are not an important part of the plot. 
The Bandillo have something that the protagonist needs to get, or get back, but I remember them having taken the item long before the hero needed to get it, and he had to visit them to get it.

Comment: We're really going to need more information here on the character. If this is a foreign word for "Bandit", then the field is very wide. Take, for example, *The Pecos Kid*, http://books.google.com/books?id=gIJ1ZA7LdqIC&pg=PT146&lpg=PT146&dq=book+%22the+bandito%22&source=bl&ots=jbWPzUruX-&sig=h_CztqifWzWlIK9mGnz6uy1gxUA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ukFJVNr9CeHlsASH5IHYDQ&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=book%20%22the%20bandito%22&f=false

Comment: What about this is science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: Ah. Apparently a "Bandillo" may be a sort of "Town Crier", particularly in the Philippines: https://ph.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080529091415AAdVQhc. Unfortunately, I don't know how that will help you.

Comment: Could you be misremembering the "Bandaloop" from Tom Robbins' "Jitterbug Perfume"?

Comment: Hello Will, If I remember the Jitterbug Perfume, it’s been a very long time, they were the ones that puts Alobar on his quest to remain young. Great coming of age story and also helps me explain the sense of smell in relation to memories, i.e. cut grass brings back the memory of childhood. But this isn’t the Bandillo that I seek. 

Richard, I hope this falls under the fantasy line of books as it was and is the most common genre of books that I read, and having a very decent memory these have evaded my recall.

Comment: @Sheprd - Unless you can point to a ***specific*** fantasy element, I don't see that this falls within the scope of the site. Just thinking it might be fantasy isn't enough.

Comment: Could it have been _bandido_, Spanish for bandit or outlaw, or even _bandit_ the Mexican word the same, but in the context of movies and popular culture about Mexican revolution?

Comment: Not SFF from the description....

Answer (score 2):

In Philip Jose Farmer's book A Feast Unknown there is a group of tribesmen called the Bandili. However while I don't remember much about the book [the Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Feast_Unknown) doesn't look much like the bits of plot you describe.